# copy asset from one ams account to another account using v3 .net sdk

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I have encoded some videos. Now I want to copy these assets to another account through azure-function. How can I do it? Say the assets get copied to another account, then do I need to encode them again or there is no need?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/ealmuneyeer/ReplicateAzureMediaServicesV3.  No reencoding required.